# Создание копий при возвращении из функции

Tags: c++

Всё глубже и глубже погружаясь в C++, я начинаю немного сходить с ума, виной этому то, что некоторые вещи я просто не могу объяснить, а заучивать отдельные случаи как-то глупо. Сейчас на моём пути конструктор копий... Сразу оговорюсь, что я использую C++ 17. Так вот, возьмём этот код

```
class A {

public:
    A() {
        cout << "construct\n";
    }

    ~A() {
        cout << "destruct\n";
    }

    A(const A &obj) {
        cout << "copy\n";
    }
};

A f() {
    A a;

    cout << &a << "\n";

    return a;
}

int main() {
    A a(f());

    cout << &a << "\n";
}
```

Результат его выполнения

```
construct
0x7ffdca371107
0x7ffdca371107
destruct
```

Честно говоря я без понятия почему результат такой. По идее при возвращении из функции должна создаваться копия объекта, затем при инициализации переменной в `main'e` должен вызываться конструктор копии этой копии объекта, в результате должны получить новый объект с новым адресом, но бит в бит такой же как его копия. Но в результате всё не так, при этом абсолютно не так. А теперь ещё для кого-то сюрприз, для кого-то нет: закомментируем обязательно и деструктор, и конструктор копии, если что-то из них останется, то это не прокатит. Теперь результат такой

```
construct
0x7fff090c99f7
0x7fff090c9a27
```

А вот это уже больше походит на то, что я написал ранее. Но всё же я не уверен, что полностью, т.к. я не могу использовать конструктор копии и деструктор, чтобы убедиться, не изменяя поведение кода. Конкретно меня интересует 2 раза ли выполнится код деструктора при инициализации переменной `a` в `main'e`. По идее 1 раз должен вызваться при завершении функции `f()`, а 2 после того, как инициализируется переменная `a`. Меня интересуют ответы на поставленные вопросы, а также логика, почему всё-таки всё работает так, а не иначе.

Comment: В С++ очень много вещей предназначенных для написания новых API и знать это всё плюс свою проблемную область довольно сложно. Но ведь можно просто написать функцию A::copy и вызывать её прямо не заморачиваясь

Comment: @PavelGridin может и можно, но тем не менее незнание данных нюансов может привести к ошибкам, обнаружить которые будет довольно сложно. Читая базовый курс C++ Шилдта, я наткнулся на пример, где в деструкторе освобождали память по указателю, который был полем класса. Таким образом, если хоть один объект данного класса уничтожался, то данный указатель ссылался уже на мусор, нарушая тем самым работу других объектов данного класса. Это просто пример, но к такому нужно быть готовым, предупреждён - значит вооружён.

Comment: ProstoCoder, если вы пишете статьи и/или учите студентов, тогда да, всё правильно. Я с точки зрения реальных задач мысли выражаю

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данном случае имеют место две оптимизации:

1. Named Returned Value Optimization - при возврате локальной переменной `a`, чья область видимости тут же оканчивается, компилятор ограничивается созданием только одной переменной - возвращаемым значением. Эта оптимизация не гарантирована, хотя почти всегда выполняется.
2. Temporary materialization - rvalue, возвращаемое функцией `f`, материализуется сразу в переменную `а` без создания временного объекта. В С++17 компилятор обязан откладывать материализацию временных переменных как можно дальше, устраняя все избыточные промежуточные объекты. Так что цепочки вида `A a{A{A{A{A{}}}}};` приводят к появлению только одного объекта, а не целой пачки, и не содержат вызовов копирующих или перемещающих конструкторов (которых может вообще не быть).

Таким образом, в функции `main` выделяется место только под один объект, который инициализируется в функции `f` минуя все промежуточные временные объекты. Причем компилятор пропускает вызовы конструкторов и деструкторов с побочными эффектами.

Comment: Интересно, почему ТС не получает NRVO, если убирает копирующий конструктор и деструктор. Может компилятор решает, что в NRVO нет необходимости? (Если добавить в класс кучу полей, то gcc снова начинает делать NRVO...)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat На этот счет где-то писали, что так как при NRVO компилятор все равно должен проверять доступность копирующего / перемещающего конструктора, то если этот конструктор не задан явно, то у компилятора на этом шаге не будет возможности быстро проверить доступность конструктора и NRVO не выполняется. Или может компилятор просто не напрягается по поводу "пустого" объекта. Хотя мне представляется, что это не должно особо мешать.